# Downloading images from Google Drive based on last letter of the file name

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-picker

I have folders of images saved on Google Drive and I need to download only the images ending with the letter Z.

Here are a few examples:

```
DJI_20210405134404_0037_Z.JPG
DJI_20210405134404_0037_W.JPG
DJI_20210405134346_0036_Z.JPG
DJI_20210405134346_0036_W.JPG
```

Is there a clever way to do this with an API or other methods?

Comment: Can I ask you about the language you want to use?

Comment: Any language will do

Answer (score 2):

Here is the example made in Laravel where using google Drive API users can filter the files based on the requirements and download multiple files.

> https://github.com/jd-patel/laravel-google-drive